# Iteratively filling a new column in a for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, imputets

I'm working with a large dataset that has multiple locations measured monthly, but each site has different number of measurement and NAs, creating a broken time series. To get around this, I've created a for loop, looped at each site, to fill in the gaps using an interpolation technique. From this, I get an interpolated output and would ideally like to add this back into the original dataset. For example:

```
library(imputeTS)

Sites = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 10))
Meas = c(25,20,NA,21,NA,23,21,22,26,27,15,20,NA,25,NA,28,28,27,NA)

df= data.frame(Sites, Meas)

for(i in Sites) {
d = subset(df, Sites = i)
d$fit = na.interpolation(d$Meas)
}
```

What I would like is to take d$fit and match it back into a new column, df$fit, such that the number of measurements and each site is matched properly. Any suggestions, or complete overhauls to my approach? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not often that you actually need for loops. You can do this particular task with the `ave()` function

```
df$fit <- ave(df$Meas, df$Sites, FUN=na.interpolation)
```

In this case the function applies the `na.interpolation` function to each of the `Meas` values for each of the different values of `Sites` and then puts everything back in the right order.

Another stragegy you could use for something more complex, is `split/unsplit`. Something like

```
ss <- split(df$Meas, df$Sites)
df$fit <- unsplit(lapply(ss, na.interpolation), df$Sites)
```